# Word VBA : Search Then Search and replace

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to search on each page of my document a name, then if that name is found, i search for another word to replace it (already on the same page) ! 
I've tried many different codes, but no efficient result found

```
  Sub Find()
  Call SearchAndMark("Article : KR", "DéfautsKR")
  Call SearchAndMark("Article : IP", "DéfautsIP")
  End Sub

  Sub SearchAndMark(searchString As String, markText As String)
  Dim CurrentPage As Integer
   Dim LastPage As Integer

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst
CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
LastPage = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)


While (CurrentPage < LastPage)
    Selection.Find.Forward = True
    Selection.Find.Text = searchString
    Selection.Find.Execute

    If Selection.Find.Found Then
            With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Défauts"
    .Replacement.Text = markText
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
End With
    Else
        CurrentPage = LastPage
    End If
 CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
Wend

 End Sub
```

Comment: What, specifically is the problem that you're having with this code? Are you seeing errors when running the code? Does it not give the expected results (in which case what results are you seeing and what did you expect)? It's a lot easier for people to help if they know what the question is.

Comment: It looks like beeing an infinite loop. This code is running in the wrong way.. i cant see the final result, because Word become not responding!!

Comment: Ok, so i need just to delete the last line in the current page, without replacing it, if it is easier !!??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by the following part of the code:

```
        'If searchString is not found, set the CurrentPage to LastPage
        'This should cause the loop to end
        CurrentPage = LastPage
    End If
    'Reset the current page to the end page for the end of the active selection
    'This will run even if searchString was not found, preventing the loop from ending
    CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
Wend
```

The line below needs to be moved to the "True" part of the If statement:
                CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

So we end up with:

```
Sub SearchAndMark(searchString As String, markText As String)
    Dim CurrentPage As Integer
    Dim LastPage As Integer

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst
    CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    LastPage = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)

    While (CurrentPage < LastPage)
        Selection.Find.Forward = True
        Selection.Find.Text = searchString
        Selection.Find.Execute

        If Selection.Find.Found Then
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = "Défauts"
                .Replacement.Text = markText
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
            End With
            CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        Else
            CurrentPage = LastPage
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

It's also worth noting that the code is not searching within specific pages. It finds an instance of searchString, then if that is found it searches for the next instance of "Défauts" and replaces it with markText. This means that if "Défauts" is above searchString on the same page, it won't be replaced. If "Défauts" appears on the following page, it will be replaced. This may be what you need, but it's not quite the same as you described above.

Comment: Thanks fo replying !! Thats the subjet, i need to replace "Défauts" found on the same page. Or simply Delete it if we can !!

Comment: We are very close to find the final solution if only we find the way to quit the loop, because now, its running in the right way, but infinte loop..

Comment: PROBLEM, The Sub Find() is running only the first Call SearchAndMark, So, The loop is being infinite !!

Comment: @HoussemAroua I'll take another look at this tomorrow if no-one else has given an answer by then.

Comment: Cant help me more in this ?